# Interactive debugger for react's react-scripts test

Tags: reactjs, debugging, jestjs, ipdb

Is there an interactive debugger for `react-scripts tests`, (unit testing on the terminal, not the browser) I've seen some examples with VSCode, yet I don't want to switch editors just for this. I've in my mind something like pdb for Python. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a section for this in the [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/debugging-tests) documentation

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned above, it only mentions browser debugging and VSCode debugging, no regular terminal debugger. It feels really weird that this isn't possible.